# Why does grafana display NaN for values that are clearly integers?

Tags: grafana, nan

I created a SQL query that counts the number of servers running test jobs on a specific Jenkins server at a specified time.  I'm trying to chart it on Grafana but for some reason, it's displaying the value as NaN.

The data source is a MySQL server.  I'm running Grafana version 8.1.5.  I went on the server (phpMyAdmin) to check the results of the query and I can see numbers.

[image]

When we look at the grafana chart/panel, the bars on the chart look like it matches the values, but the chart shows NaN instead of the value.

[image]

What setting do I need to change so that it can print the numeric value on the chart instead of displaying NaN?

EDIT: Looks like I didn't include enough info to my question.

Here's the query that's used, although, I don't know how feasible it is to include the tables with data to demo the issue:

> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tb_name)) as val, jenkins FROM (
> SELECT
> hw.collected_date AS mytime,
> hw.jenkins AS jenkins,
> hw.name AS tb_name
> FROM hw_report as hw LEFT OUTER JOIN jenkins_owner jo
> ON hw.jenkins = jo.jenkins
> WHERE jo.org IN ('Enterprise Readiness')) as y
> WHERE mytime = '2021-12-03 00:00:00'
> GROUP BY jenkins
> HAVING count(distinct(tb_name)) > '0'

Here are screenshots of my panel.  The "Show values" setting is set to "Always", which II assume should show the values.

[image]

One thing I noticed is when I hover over the bar, it shows

```
COUNT(DISTINCT(name_cnt))
```

instead of a numeric value.  Not sure if this is indicative of anything.  I checked other charts in the dashboard that someone created and their bars either have a numeric value or it's just a column name (like name_cnt)

Comment: Because you have wrong query, wrong panel configuration, ... You didn't provide reproducible example, so any answer will be only guess.

Comment: @JanGaraj, thx for looking and trying to help me.  I added some more details which hopefully gives more insight into my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm a noob and didn't know what to configure, look up, or mention in my question.  I accidentally came across the answer.

So it seems like I need to select something under the "Transform" tab for the panel.  Calculation needs to be "Total" instead of "Count" and I need to hide the fields specified in my SQL query and show the "Total"

[image]